# IIS/MSSQL HA on two servers? NLB + Mirroring

Tags: high-availability, database-mirroring, nlb

We currently have the one server doing MSSQL/IIS. Can use NLB with two servers running IIS for HA and can use database mirroring and put the failover partner in the connection string for HA.

**Can we use NLB + Mirroring together?** So if one of the servers died (ie power plug removed), everything will continue to work (after the timeout for the mirror to become the principal)?

Comment: will this work: bump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is yes it should work once you get NLB & the SQL mirror configured correctly.